# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method mGetAlternateIconName on channel dynamic_icon_flutter)

Tags: android, flutter

Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method mGetAlternateIconName on channel dynamic_icon_flutter). I’m facing this issue in android, can anyone faced with this one? there is any solution ?

Comment: MissingPluginException is only happens when i add the package while running the app. I rectified this issue by stop run. and `flutter clean` then `flutter run`

Comment: Yeah, I tried to flutter clean. Even I delete the app. but unfortunately it doesn’t help